# How do I keep HTML Tidy from encoding IDNs?

Tags: tidy, idn

I'm using HTML Tidy, and out of something like

```
<a href="http://www.äöü.com/">Link</a>
```

it makes

```
<a href="http://www.%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%BC.de/">Link</a>
```

How do I tell Tidy to keep the links the way they are?

My configuration:

```
'output-xhtml' => true,
'numeric-entities' => true,
'hide-comments' => false,
'show-body-only' => true,
'doctype' => 'transitional',
'wrap' => 0,
'alt-text' => '',
'word-2000' => true,
'drop-proprietary-attributes' => true
```

I've also tried to disable `fix-uri` and to set `char-encoding` to `utf8`, but to no avail.

The reason why I want to do this is because Firefox has recently had trouble with this kind of URL encoding. Try to visit www.v%C3%A4terwiderstand.de in the latest version of Firefox (I can't make an actual link out of it, since stackoverflow seems to be unable to handle domains with umlauts as well), and you'll see a "server not found" error. Simply hitting enter in the URL bar afterwards will open the website fine, though. This does not happen in other browsers, as far as I'm aware.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your ENV looks like etc but this works; `fix-uri=no|0` is all that was required for me. I added the `char-encoding` argument for good measure. Perl's tidy wraps the tidy lib so this should be valid for most/any tidy use after converting the arguments.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strictures;
use utf8;
use open qw( :std :utf8 );
use HTML::Tidy;

print HTML::Tidy
    ->new({ "show-body-only" => 1,
            "char-encoding" => "utf8",
            "fix-uri" => 0, })
    ->clean(q{<a href="http://www.äöü.com/">Link</a>});

__END__
<a href="http://www.äöü.com/">Link</a>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but your solution is absolutely correct. `fix-uri` removes that behaviour. My problem was caused by the system I was working with. I could change those options around merrily and never see any difference because another part of the system was overwriting the settings again. Oh well!